# Duplicates of questions in other language

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

We have a new question:

- [Verbos en pasado que tienen una "s" extra al final](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2583/12)

Which appears to be an exact duplicate of an older one:

- ["s" final en tiempo pretérito indefinido: -aste(s), -iste(s)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1435/12)

The only problem is the old one is in English, and the new one is in Spanish.

I would like to propose that whenever we come across this scenario, we translate the original one to Spanish *before* we close the new one as a duplicate.

We may also wish to do the reverse (if a new English question is a dupe of an old Spanish one), but I think this is less important, as we're trying to move toward Spanish as our main language.

Comment: This is why I didn't close it, it's just I don't have time now to translate it.  Maybe the OP or someone else can do it.

Comment: I'm glad we're on the same page :)

Comment: (Another option would be to mark the English version as a duplicate of the Spanish version... that might be seen as a bit heavy-handed, though)

Comment: I don't think it's fair for the user who asked first, I'd go with translating to Spanish as you proposed.

Comment: About the reverse, I would translate to English in the case the user can't understand Spanish, and then close as dupe.

Comment: @JoulSauron: Tried to translate it, feel free to correct.

Comment: @jrdioko done. Your Spanish is perfect, I think you should always ask in Spanish. When I have time, I'll translate my answer as well.

Comment: Shouldn't we translate the accepted answer as well? If someone can't speak English well, it's quite useless to translate the question and close the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer just in case anybody was left wondering.

AFAIK, the currently accepted way of tackling this kind of duplicates is to mark the duplicate question as such, and edit the referenced answer to include a translation to the missing language (be it English or Spanish).

Comment: Yup, this was addressed in another question. It is in Spanish... and yes, I marked this as a duplicate even though they are in a different language :D