# Do we want duplicate answers in different languages?

Tags: discusión, respuestas, idioma-de-la-publicación, duplicados-exactos

There has been discussion about duplicate questions in different languages ([1](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2524/24236), [2](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/248/24236), [3](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/24236)). The consensus was that, if two questions are the same but in different languages (Spanish and English in our case), one should be marked as a duplicate of the other.

The [policy](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/69/24236) on the language of answers is to prefer answering in the same language as the question, but to also allow answers in the other language.

However, I have not found any discussion on duplicate answers in different languages. It happens sometimes that a user answers a question in one language, and another user adds another answer with the same information in the other language (maybe even a direct translation). This can be helpful to users that are not fluent in one of the two languages, but it has sometimes caused complaints from the first answerer saying that the second answer does not add any new information.

So should we accept answers with the same information in different languages?

Comment: Regardless of the language, if the answer brings something new, of course it's valid. But, if someone makes the effort to answer in the language in which the question was asked and a couple of hours later he/she reads the same answer from another user who feels more comfortable writing in another language and uses it to "decorate" it with accessory content around the same axis, it's a bit annoying & can lead to a bad practice: copy the answer in whatever language it is, translate it, add 4 words and that's it. Once can be understandable, the problem is when it starts to be a repetitive pattern

Comment: Siendo como es un sitio con comportamientos relativamente amables entre usuarios, lo mismo puede plantearse que si alguien quiere añadir la versión traducida de una respuesta, que lo haga libremente. De hecho, es lo que se ha venido haciendo en las [tag:preguntas-canónicas].

Comment: @Danielillo if you feel that the copying has been done in bad faith you can always flag it for moderator attention.